# populus OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyethereum, solc, ubuntu, populus

#### When trying:

```
$populus compile
```

#### Get:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

#### Tried:

Tried to install missing dependencies as described [here](https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/issues/49) and [installed solidity compiler](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#ubuntu-trusty-14-04) as well - same result. And same result under sudo or virtualenv. **populus init** works as expected.

Related [issue](https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/issues/80) at GitHub.

#### Full console output:

```
============ Compiling ==============
> Loading contracts from: /home/petr/Projects/populus-tests/contracts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/populus", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1060, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/populus/cli/compile_cmd.py", line 46, in compile_contracts
    result = compile_and_write_contracts(project_dir, *filters, optimize=optimize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/populus/compilation.py", line 161, in compile_and_write_contracts
    **compiler_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/populus/compilation.py", line 94, in compile_project_contracts
    **compiler_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/populus/compilation.py", line 81, in compile_source_file
    **compiler_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/populus/solidity.py", line 52, in solc
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing some other tools (like EthereumJS [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc)) the problem was solved by itself. I guess it was solc compiler which wasn't installed properly on my computer.

Used to build [solidity compiler](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html) from source but then installed it as a npm package, which was much easier.

So, if you have the same problem. Try checking if **solc** command works.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Apart from `solc` it also depends on `lllc` command.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you do not have a directory:

```
/home/petr/Projects/populus-tests/contracts
```

Is that the case? If yes create it and copy your contract source files into it.

Comment: No, the directory is there. It was created by populus init command.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/populus.overview.html#initialize) for `populus init`:

> Running $ populus init will initialize the current directory with the
>   default project layout that populus uses.
>
> ./contracts/
>   ./contracts/Example.sol
>   ./tests/test_examply.py
>   ./html/index.html
>   ./assets/

Note that it initialises the *current* directory - i.e. from where you're running the command, meaning that `populus compile` should be run in the same directory, and by default will compile `./contracts/Example.sol`.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I'm using the right location. There is something different.

Comment: Does `Example.sol` definitely exist? And you're running from the same directory as `init` was run from?

Comment: Sure. Please see the very first link in the question. Second line there says the problem may occur when the solc compiler is not installed. But I did install it.